# Does anyone have a link to the American Local News Corpus V1.0?

Tags: english, corpora, american-english

I found a paper http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~anni/papers/alnc_lrec14.pdf that has made this epic text corpus of over 1 billion words available somewhere, but I can't find it anywhere online.

The paper says

> Version 1.0 is available for research use

Does anyone have a working link?

Comment: Is it possible to contact the authors of the paper?

Comment: @jknappen I've contacted them yesterday and got a reply! If I get a link, I'll see if I can post it here too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I contacted a couple of the authors and got some links!

The primary author said:

> You can download the raw corpus here:
>   [www.cs.jhu.edu/~anni/ALNC/030314corpus.cleaned.tgz](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~anni/ALNC/030314corpus.cleaned.tgz)
>
> And the preprocessed corpus here:
>   [www.cs.jhu.edu/~anni/ALNC/030314corpus.splittoklc.tgz](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~anni/ALNC/030314corpus.splittoklc.tgz)
>
> Note that these files contain version 1.1 of sorts; slightly more data
>   than reported in the LREC paper. Each file is about 8GB.

I will update when I have the complete uncompressed sizes.

Comment: Do you have any information if they have updated the corpus? Or is it the same as of 20XX?